# Pulp - Constraints

Tags: python, pulp

I'm essentially trying to emulate an excel problem in pulp, thus far I think that the problem was frame correctly, with the exception of the constraints, in essence, the constraints compare the demand for each flight with the estimated demand, that depends on one of the variables from solver

[image: Solver in Exce;]

My Python Code is below:

```
import pulp
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data_flight = pd.read_csv('data_flight.csv')
resource = pd.read_csv('Resource_Requirement.csv')

seat_capacity = pd.read_csv('seat_capacity.csv')

products = list(data_flight['Product j'])
flight_capacity = list(seat_capacity["Type"])

dict_price = dict(zip(products,data_flight['Price']))
dict_demand = dict(zip(products,data_flight['Exp. Demand']))
dict_y = dict(zip(products,list(np.arange(0,14))))

resource_req = {}
for i in flight_capacity:
    resource_req[i] = resource[i]


phasing = pulp.LpProblem("Maximise",pulp.LpMaximize)
phasing += pulp.lpSum(Selection[idx]*data_flight.loc[idx, 'Price'] for idx in data_flight.index)

from pulp import lpDot
constraint_seats = []
for i in flight_capacity:
    constraint_seats.append(lpDot(resource_req[i], Selection))

for i, j in zip(seat_capacity['Seat Capacity'], constraint_seats):
    phasing += j <= i

for i,j in zip(data_flight['Exp. Demand'],Selection):
    phasing += j <= i

phasing.solve()
```

After solving I'm getting an error, so pulp is not really solving anything, and I think the problem is that my constraints are setup incorrectly

Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[30], line 1
----> 1 phasing.solve()

File ~/.python/current/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pulp/pulp.py:1913, in LpProblem.solve(self, solver, **kwargs)
   1911 # time it
   1912 self.startClock()
-> 1913 status = solver.actualSolve(self, **kwargs)
   1914 self.stopClock()
   1915 self.restoreObjective(wasNone, dummyVar)

File ~/.python/current/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pulp/apis/coin_api.py:137, in COIN_CMD.actualSolve(self, lp, **kwargs)
    135 def actualSolve(self, lp, **kwargs):
    136     """Solve a well formulated lp problem"""
--> 137     return self.solve_CBC(lp, **kwargs)

File ~/.python/current/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pulp/apis/coin_api.py:206, in COIN_CMD.solve_CBC(self, lp, use_mps)
    204     if pipe:
    205         pipe.close()
--> 206     raise PulpSolverError(
    207         "Pulp: Error while trying to execute, use msg=True for more details"
    208         + self.path
    209     )
    210 if pipe:
    211     pipe.close()

PulpSolverError: Pulp: Error while trying to execute, use msg=True for more details/home/codespace/.python/current/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pulp/solverdir/cbc/linux/64/cbc
```

Comment: What error? Please provide the full traceback and a way to reproduce your problem (need data).

Comment: Do you have any of these [conditions](https://coin-or.github.io/pulp/guides/how_to_debug.html#jupyter-notebooks-anaconda-conda-issues)?

Comment: Your `pulp` code is not set up well.  There are no variables... ???.  If this is your first try at a `pulp` model, I would start out with a small...very small version of your problem and just get something working, then build on it.  Say forget about the different flights, etc. and just try to fill 1 set of seats (like 1 plane) that has a max capacity, seat price, and budget.  That will give you confidence to add to it.  If you get stuck and re-post a question, include a small set of data so that your problem executes.  Either a snippet of the csv's or data in dictionaries.

Comment: Please include sample CSV content so that others can reproduce this